# Bound on $Q$ implies bound on $R$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth, closed Riemannian manifold with dimension $n>4$. Define the $Q$-curvature through the formula

$Q = \Delta R + \frac{n^3-4n^2+16n-16}{(n-1)(n-2)^2} R^2 - \frac{8(n-1)}{(n-2)^2}|Ric|^2,$

where $\Delta = -div\nabla$, $R$ is the scalar curvature, and $|Ric|$ is the norm of the Ricci tensor. This quantity arises in many problems in conformal differential geometry. The question is whether or not a uniform sup-norm bound on a sequence of $Q$ curvatures implies there exists a uniform sup-norm bound on the corresponding scalar curvatures, provided that all of the scalar curvatures change sign?

Comment: Why do you believe such a sup norm bound exists? Is there an analogous situation where it does? And how does "all of the scalar curvatures change sign" help?

Comment: Deane: The mode situation is where there is a sequence of metrics with constant $Q$ curvature, where the constant is bounded uniformly. The changing signs hypothesis is there to prevent situations where the scalar curvature simply "translates its way to infinity".

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you mean by the scalar curvature "translates its way to infinity"?

Comment: I haven't checked the constants in $n$-dimensional case but I found a formula for $Q$ in dimension 4. In dimension 4 the maximum principle gives an upper bound for $R$ in terms of $Q$ and the traceless part of Ricci. I'm sure that's known to everybody who works with $Q$-curvature. Does this work in higher dimensions?

Comment: Deane: In four dimensions the formula is special because it contains the conformal Laplacian of the scalar curvature, so, yes, higher dimensions are different. By "translate to infinity" I mean to rule out $R$ becoming unbounded like the sequence $\{R+n\}$. The idea is that if the Laplacian of $R$ is controlled it my prevent blow-up.

Comment: Deane: In higher dimensions you could be able to use the maximum principle to get a bound in terms of $Q$ and $E$ (traceless Ricci tensor), but the aim is to get it to depend on $Q$ only.

Comment: By now, I'm rather confused. First, do you know examples of sequences where the scalar curvature does not change sign and becomes unbounded but the $Q$-curvature does not? Second, why do you believe it should be possible to bound the scalar curvature in terms of the $Q$-curvature only (and not the traceless Ricci)?

Comment: Deane: an example of this type of sequence would be one where $g_n = u^\frac{4}{n-4}g$, where $u$ is a bubble in the sense of Hebey and Robert. Here we are also assuming that the Yamabe constant of $g$ is negative. I believe there is hope for such a bound, because it might be impossible for $\Delta R$ to blow-up at the same rate as $R^2$ and $|Ric|^2$.

Comment: Thanks! I guess one approach would be to argue by contradiction and use a blow-up argument. But you usually still need some assumptions on integral bounds on curvature. In dimension 4 you get some for free from topological invariants. But in higher dimensions this usually needs to be an explicit assumption, no?